# Wrong tag synonym: psql -> PostgreSQL

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

[psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html) is the interactive command-line terminal of the RDBMS `PostgreSQL`. Those two are in no way synonymous. [`Postgres` is a widely-used nickname for PostgreSQL, `psql` isn't](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_PostgreSQL.3F_How_is_it_pronounced.3F_What_is_Postgres.3F).

There are a number of questions that explicitly deal with `psql`, not directly with `PostgreSQL`. Some examples:

[Insert a database dump with ruby-pg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11456916/939860)
[Shebang for psql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995326/shebang-for-psql)
[subprocess.popen and psql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019722/subprocess-popen-and-psql)
[How to switch databases in psql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949876/how-to-switch-databases-in-psql)
[How to make psql completion with Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1258371/939860)

Yet, a [tag synonym has been approved on May 23](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=creator&filter=all) - created by a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/537031/grailsguy) that provided a total of 4 answers tagged [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql).
I see no way to correct this mistake [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/synonyms) or anywhere. Or at least to vote for it. I think such a **feature** would be generally well received.

**For now** it seems I need an admin to lend a hand?
It just encourages - nay forces! - incorrect use of terms. Can we please fix this?

Comment: @Robert: Thanks for lending a hand. I have created a tag wiki and tagged a couple of typical posts to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

For what I can find on the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/app-psql.html):

> psql --  PostgreSQL interactive terminal

Being the [official description](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/app-psql.html#AEN52179) for psql:

> psql is a terminal-based front-end to PostgreSQL. It enables you to type in queries interactively, issue them to PostgreSQL, and see the query results. Alternatively, input can be from a file. In addition, it provides a number of meta-commands and various shell-like features to facilitate writing scripts and automating a wide variety of tasks.

And one can also read about it on [http://postgresguide.com - What is psql](http://postgresguide.com/utilities/psql.html).

---

## misleading informations

At first glance if one does know about psql and doesn't dig further, the examples bellow may lead to the conclusion that "PostgreSQL" -> shorted to -> "Psql":

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psql) the information may lead visitors to wrong conclusions:

> **PSQL** can refer to:
>
> - PostgreSQL
> - Pervasive PSQL

Also from [What is psql? - Yahoo! Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=1005122701287) a misleading information:

> If you are referring to PSQL it is PostgreSQL. The first link gives more information.

A Google Search using a simple ["what is psql ?"](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20is%20psql%20?&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=ubuntu&channel=fs) leads to this:

[image: Google Print-Screen]

---

**I agree that this is a wrong tag synonym**, and should be reversed.
Perhaps a proper tag wiki for the [psql](/questions/tagged/psql) would help clarify the confusion.

Comment: A proper tag wiki for `psql` certainly is in order. But I can't do anything about that, as long as it is registered as synonym for PostgreSQL. Catch 22 ... Also, I added `psql` on the Wikipedia disambiguation page for clarity.